# Complex Exponentials to Trig Functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, trigonometry

I have an expression

```
expr = 1/2 a E^(-3 I ω t) (E^(3 I ω t)+2 Cos[π x/a]) (1+2 E^(3 I ω t) Cos[π x/a]) Sin[π x/a]^2;
expr // TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{2} a e^{-3 i t \omega } \sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{a}\right) \left(2 \cos
>    \left(\frac{\pi  x}{a}\right)+e^{3 i t \omega }\right) \left(1+2 e^{3 i t \omega }
>    \cos \left(\frac{\pi  x}{a}\right)\right)$

It is in complex exponential form, and I need it in trigonometric form. How do I do this? I see that in the Wolfram Language (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ComplexNumbers.html) there is a function for it, but I do not seem to be able to use that, for when I enter it as an argument, nothing changes. I am using Mathematica 11.3. How would I go about getting this into trigonometric form?
[image: Down at the bottom is the expression with complex terms I want to change to trigonometric terms]

Comment: it looks like you need to add SPACE between some letter. As in `Pi x` and not `Pix` and same for `Iwt` try with `I w t`. There is also a function call `TrigToExp` you can try. SPACE is important in Mathematica, unlike in Latex (most of the time). So `Pix` is not the same as `Pi x` which internally becomes `Pi*x`. I actually prefer to write explicit `*` and not use SPACE. For me, it is more clear and also this way I do not make the same mistake as you did by accident.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ExpToTrig`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpToTrig):

```
expr = 1/2 a E^(-3 I ω t) (E^(3 I ω t)+2 Cos[π x/a]) (1+2 E^(3 I ω t) Cos[π x/a]) Sin[π x/a]^2;

ExpToTrig[expr] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{2} a \sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{a}\right) (\cos (3 t \omega )-i \sin (3 t \omega
>    )) \left(2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  x}{a}\right)+i \sin (3 t \omega )+\cos (3 t \omega
>    )\right) \left(2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  x}{a}\right) \cos (3 t \omega )+2 i \cos
>    \left(\frac{\pi  x}{a}\right) \sin (3 t \omega )+1\right)$

Comment: `expr // ExpToTrig // FullSimplify` will provide a cleaner form.